# Write arabic in Java file in Android

Tags: java, android, arabic

Hi I want to write Arabic in Java in Android and this is the code

```
public class hospital extends Activity {

    ListView listView,l1;



    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter,adapter1,adapter2;
    String[] location,loc1,loc2;
    Button home,map;
    TextView name,address,phone;
    WebView maps;
    String hospital_name,hospital_address,hospital_phone,url;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hospital_location);

         home = (Button)findViewById(R.id.home);
        home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(hospital.this, MainActivity.class ));
                finish();
            }
        });



        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.hospital_list_location);

        location = new String[] { "Al rabia","Tabarbor","Tla' al Ali","Daheat elrawda" };
```

This code will write like in the photo

[image]

And when I want to write Arabic in location like this. `location=new String[]{"مستشفى هبه"}`
It's want work and appear a strange words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android can't handle the simple arabic letters (unicode 0x06xx). You need to use arabic presentation characters (0xFExx), and join the letters together yourself.

You also need to find a nice arabic font on the web- I use "AGA Rashheeq Bold"- and put it into your assets, then load it like this

```
Typeface tfArabic = Typeface.createFromAsset (getAssets (), "AGA-Rasheeq-Bold.ttf");
```

Then use something like this to use the font:

```
NextButton.setTypeface (tfArabic);
```